# Grave accent symbol in monospace in GitHub commit message

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I want to make exactly this commit message: """ swap `` ` `` and `'` """
(apostrophe and grave must be in monospace)

So i'm writing: ``` swap `` ` `` and `'` ```
but what i get is: """ swap `` ``` \``  and ```  '` """

[Demonstration](https://github.com/dmyTRUEk/grave_in_commit_msg)

So what should i write, to get desired commit message?

Comment: Git itself will preserve whatever *byte sequence* it gets. If you use `git commit` on your laptop and bring up your editor and use your editor to insert the desired byte sequence, that's what you'll get. If you use some *web interface* to shovel stuff through some connection that edits what you give it and passes that on, you'll need to figure out how to get *that* software to pass the right byte-sequence *to* Git. So your best bet is to make the commit locally, where you have full control. Once a commit exists, nothing—not even Git itself—can ever *change* that commit.

Comment: Yes, i'm using git from terminal and inputing commit message via pure vim. The question isn't about git itself, it's about how GitHub represents exact _byte sequence_. Also, commits' messages can be changed via `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and then `git push --force` ;)

Comment: That doesn't change the commit's message. That makes a *new and different commit* (with a different message). The term "monospace" makes relatively little sense when you talk about command line Git, since there are no font controls here.

Comment: So then wouldn't this be about GitHub Markdown, and nothing at all to do with Git?

Comment: Yeah, you right. Fixed tags.